# Installing Thrift with Python bindings on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: python, windows-7, cassandra, thrift, pycassa

I am trying to install [pycassa](http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/installation.html), a Cassandra client in Python, on Windows 7.

Running `pip install pycassa` I got this error message:

```
error: unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Digging deeper, I found that Python failed to install the thrift library and Python bindings. One way people suggest is to install a C++ compiler, such as [Visual Studio 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2008-editions/express#2008-Visual-CPP), or [mingw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/) on Windows 7, and compile Thrift from source.

However, I found an [online compiled version of Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/download/index.html).
Is there a way to bind the compiled version of Thrift into Python and then use it in pycassa? Or do I have to go through compiling thrift from source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thrift really has two (kinds of) components: there's the Thrift compiler, which generates code given an interface, and then there are the per-language libraries, which implement the low-level thrift protocols and transports for each language.

You almost certainly don't need the Thrift compiler, which is what you linked to.  You *do* need the Thrift python library; pip attempts to install this as a dependency for pycassa.  The reason that it's breaking is that there is a C extension that is included in the Thrift python library, and during the installation process, it tries to compile that.  For the compilation to work, you need to do a few things specially.

If you're just doing this for development purposes, you can download the latest [Thrift python library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/thrift/0.7.0) manually, remove src/protocol/fastbinary.c, and then run 'setup.py install' from the top-level directory.  This will be slower than if you have the extension compiled and installed, but for dev purposes, it will work fine.  You can use 'pip install --no-deps pycassa' at this point, and it won't try to install Thrift automatically, just pycassa.

If you're doing this for production, you will likely want the C extension to be compiled and installed.  To do this, you need to install [Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/), check out the latest version of Thrift from SVN, go to the lib/py directory, and run 'setup.py install' there.

Comment: Thank you very much Tyler. I also needed to remove the fastbinary extension from setup.py, but other than that, it works fine.

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot to include that.  Thanks for mentioning that.